In azure dev Ops, how to publish test result and code coverage from PR Validation Build?
Thanks to this answer, I'm now able to get the artefact generated by the PR validation build in the classic editor in the build before release
In the PR validation build I generate a code coverage report and test reports. I would like to publish them in the build before release without having to generate them again.
How can I do that?

As suggested in my answer below, you can use pipelines resource to share the artifacts files from one pipeline to another.  @CedricArnould

In Azure pipelines, if you have generated the result files for tests and code coverage but not published them, you can use the following two built-in tasks to publish the results:

Publish Test Results task: Publish test results to Azure Pipelines.
Publish code coverage results task: Publish code coverage results to Azure Pipelines.

On the tasks, you can provide the path of the result files generated by the previous test task.

EDIT:
If you want to pass the artifact files from a pipeline to another, you can consider using pipelines resource.
Below is a sample to show how to do this:

Suppose there are two pipelines (pipelineA and pipelineB) in the same Azure DevOps project. The pipelineA runs build and tests to generates the artifact files test result file and code coverage result file. Need to pass the result files to pipelineB.

In pipelineA, use the PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task to publish the result files as an pipeline artifact.
steps:
. . . previous steps to run build and test . . .

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact files'
  inputs:
    targetPath: path/to/the/folder/contains/the/result/files
    artifact: drop
    publishLocation: pipeline


In pipelineB, set pipelineA as a pipelines resource. and then use the download task to download the artifact from the pipelineA.
Here I also set 'trigger: true', once a run of pipelineA is completed successfully, it will automatically trigger a new run of pipelineB, and the download task will download the artifact from that run of pipelineA.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeA
    source: pipelineA
    trigger: true

. . .

steps:
- download: pipeA
  displayName: 'Download Artifact files from pipelineA'
  artifact: 'drop'

. . . subsequent steps to publish test and code coverage result . . .





Thanks for the help. I can see from my previous build the artefacts containing the code coverage and the build. But I don't find a way to publish the code coverage folder from the previous build to the new build. I would like to avoid to do it a second time.

@CedricArnould, you can consider using pipelines resource. For more details, see EDIT in my above answer.
